# How to install usbnet driver on kernel 2.4.23-2.5-ts/

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, embedded-linux

I searched in the directory "/usr/lib/modules/2.4.23-2.5-ts/kernel/drivers/net/usb/" for the 
usbnet but i didn't find it so how can i install the usbnet driver,i don't know where to start or how to install the driver/kernel object

Answer (score 0):

In v2.4 kernels, the driver was located at **`drivers/usb/usbnet.c`**.

(It was moved to `drivers/usb/net/usbnet.c` somewhere in v2.5.x, and later to `drivers/net/usb/usbnet.c` only in v2.6.22.)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to know by heart where files are located on your system: you may search for them as follows:

```
  sudo find / -name 'usbnet*' -print
```

This will locate a file or directory of name usbnet* (i.e., usbnet followed by *any* string of characters), starting from the directory / (i.e., in this case your whole file hyerarchy), and then output the result of its search.